# Trouble with excel formula, I have a value say 1234.23.45 , want to remove decimal

Tags: excel, formula

Trouble with excel formula, I have a value say 1234.23.45  and i want to remove only one decimal keeping the decimal as it is which is coming before 4 in above example. Final output should be 123423.45. I have more than 10000 values in different columns. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say A1 = 1234.23.45

In cell B1, type

```
= (LEFT(A1, FIND(".", A1) - 1) & MID(A1, FIND(".", A1) + 1, 1000)) * 1
```

You are concatenating everything to the left of the first decimal with everything to the right of it.  Multiplying the result by one coerces the string back to a float.

Comment: Could you tick the green box for the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your string in A1 always contains two decimal points and you want to remove the first one then use the `SUBSTITUTE` function in B1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",,1)
```

This looks in A1 (param 1) for the first instance (param 4) of "." (param 2) and replaces it with param 3 which is nothing.

If you want to use the result as a number then wrap it in a `VALUE` function.

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",,1))`